# Problem with length of data in .txt file. printing all line is not possible

Tags: perl

I am doing Perl code for some time. Recently I had a strange issue with my Perl code.

My goal is to print all lines in text file and also get count how many lines are there in Perl file.

My Perl version: Active Perl 5.12

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $line;
my @list = ();
my $input = "D:\\Test\\input.txt";

open(FILE, "$input") or die("unable to open file");
@list = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

foreach $line(@list)
{
    print"$line\n";
    $count++;
}

print "Count is: $count\n";
```

**My input.txt has more than 200 lines like below format:**

AC2CG000218_SW_VERSION.zip

AC2CG000219_SW_VERSION.zip

**My output is stopping after 146th entry :**

Below data copied from command prompt output

AC2CG000145_SW_VERSION.zip

AC2CG000146_SW_VERSION.zip

AC2CG000

count is: 147

**My expected output is:**

I am expecting all lines to print from input and count is 218

Comment: Could you format properly your code please? Also, there is no apparent reason for your code to stop working after 146 inputs. Please create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and provide us with inputs, outputs, and code that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: If you're asking a large group of strangers for help with your code, the very least you can do is to format it so that we can read it easily.

Comment: If it's working why I will post a question. I checked with some of my friends and colleagues and also I verified on google and not able to found a workaround. That's why I decide to post my question.

Comment: I fixed your syntax error. You had a colon instead of a semi-colon after `warnings`.

Comment: Thanks, Brain! I re-typed code so I missed it :(

Comment: Yes, never retype code. Cut and paste the real code.

Comment: Are those spaces in `< FILE >` actually in the real code?

Comment: It seems suspicious that 146 x (26+2)char +  8char = 4096 bytes (assuming `\r\n` line-endings)

Comment: @briandfoy still I have some issues. I used your logic. But I am creating text files in my code and doing read lines and count. Then your logic is not working :(

Comment: @briandfoy, could you please help me to understand why my code is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simplify your program quite a bit. Most of the work you are doing Perl already does for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# take the filename from the command-line argument
my $input = $ARGV[0];

# open it and look at the special variable $! to see why
# it didn't work
open my $fh, '<', $input or die "unable to open file: $!";

# read it line by line with while, using the $. variable to 
# show the line number (instead of your own counter).
while( <$fh> ) {
    print "$. $_";  # LINE NO: LINE
    }

print "Total lines was $.\n";
```

Running this on itself gives this output:

```
1   use strict;
2   use warnings;
3
4   # take the filename from the command-line argument
5   my $input = $ARGV[0];
6
7   # open it and look at the special variable $! to see why
8   # it didn't work
9   open my $fh, '<', $input or die "unable to open file: $!";
10
11  # read it line by line with while, using the $. variable to
12  # show the line number (instead of your own counter).
13  while( <$fh> ) {
14      print "$. $_";  # LINE NO: LINE
15      }
16
17 print "Total lines was $.\n";
Total lines was 17
```

Beyond that, I can't say more without seeing your entire input file. My first suspect is that `< FILE >` with spaces is weird. That doesn't read from a filehandle. What happens if you write it as `<FILE>` with no spaces or as `readline(FILE)`?

You'll learning all this stuff in [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com).

Comment: Hello Brian! If I run simply above code it's working fine by parsing txt file. But I have large code and the text file is creating from one part of code and using that text file to above code there again it's not working

Answer (score -2):

I've slightly modified your code and made it easier to read

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = shift
    or die "Provide filename";

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my @lines = <$fh>;

close $fh;

chomp @lines;

my $total_lines = @lines;

say for (@lines);

say "\nTotal lines: $total_lines";
```